# Função date com duas variáveis

Tags: php, mysql, data, strtotime

Estou a tentar concatenar uma data e hora de forma a ficarem com o valor (ISO) em MySQL para que os consiga inserir na base de dados.
A linha de código é esta:

Exemplo: `datai = 20/04/2018` e `horai = 14:27`

```
$data = '$_POST[datai]';
$data2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($data)); // converter para formato definido
$hora = '$_POST[horai]'.':00'; // adicionar segundos à hora
$datahora = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($data2.''.$hora));
```

Porém, o que é recebido na bd é:

```
1970-01-01 01:00:00
```

Conseguem-me explicar se é possível concatenar data e hora desta forma? São dois inputs diferentes.

A query à base de dados é esta:

```
$inserirdatahora = mysqli_query ($conexao,"UPDATE minha_tabela 
SET data_de_inicio = '$datahora' WHERE (id = 10)");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resposta que transforma duas variáveis em uma só e que converte de `dd/mm/yyyy` para `yyyy-mm-dd` e adiciona dois '0' no final do tempo (de 8:00 para 08:00:00).

```
$date1 = strtr($_POST['datai'], '/', '-');
$date2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1));
$hora = $_POST['horai'].':00';
$datahora = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("{$date2} {$hora}"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possível, mas como você definiu `$data` como `'$_POST[datai]'`, a variável receberá a *string* `'$_POST[datai]'` literal, não o valor de `$_POST['datai']`, pois você utilizou aspas simples. Como a função `strtotime` não reconhece esse padrão, ao invés de dar erro ela definirá a data padrão (típico do PHP não avisar o desenvolvedor que há algo errado). O mesmo acontece com `$_POST['horai']`.

O PHP só avalia o valor de uma variável dentro da *string* quando é utilizado aspas duplas, tal como em `"Você informou a data {$data}"`, porém, neste caso, por quê as aspas? Todos os dados que vem pela requisição HTTP, por definição, são *string*, então é desnecessário fazer `"$_POST['datai']"`.

A alternativa correta seria:

```
$data = $_POST['datai'];
$hora = $_POST['horai']; // amém
$datahora = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("{$data} {$hora}"));
```

Comment: @RBZ não, pois as variáveis não seriam avaliadas. A *string* ficaria literal. [Veja a diferença](https://ideone.com/0mWnYf).

Comment: Acabei de testar. Entendi agora ! rs

Comment: Percebi muito bem a resposta, porém ainda não ficou a funcionar... Não tenho de acrescentar o ":00" à hora por exemplo? A query é inserida com aspas certo?

Comment: @White Quanto ao adicionar os zeros, depende do que você está passando via post. E na SQL, sim, deverá ter aspas, mas só na SQL, não na variável em si.

Comment: Estou a passar por exemplo 25-10-2017 e 8:00 para horas, como passo isto para ISO já com o código em cima?

Comment: @White não consigo entender onde você ainda pode ter dificuldade. Você chegou a testar a solução? Com essas entradas o código funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Alterei a pergunta em cima com exemplo de input, consegue ajudar? Eu sei que estamos muito perto de resolver, mas falta-me qualquer coisa...

Comment: Mas você mudou o formato da data. No comentário está com hífen, na pergunta está com barra. Isso faz toda diferença para datas. Quando usa barras, o padrão é `mm/dd/yyyy` e não `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Comment: Mas é com "/", peço desculpa. É possível ajudar?

Comment: Então é só passar de barra para hífen que funcionará.

Comment: dd-mm-YYYY desta forma?